# Azure notification hub deletes expired registrations

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

The documentation of the Azure Notification Hub's [Registration Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management) states that

> By default, registrations and installations do not expire.

But whenever a new device is registered with the Azure notification hub using `NotificationHub.Start()` (from the Xamarin.Forms app) method the `ExpirationTime` property is set with 90 days ahead of the current date.

When I was fetching all the registrations yesterday there were 2 registrations both had `"ExpirationTime": "2023-06-21"`. When I fetched today, those two registrations were removed. As expected, those two devices didn't get any notifications as well.

Any explanation for this behavior, or am I missing something in my code?

Answer (score 0):

- Registrations and installations do not expire by default. When a new device is registered with the Azure notification hub through Notification Hub, however the expiration time attribute of the `Start()` method is set to 90 days ahead of the current date in default.
- Regarding your current issue, it's possible that the registrations disappeared due to an issue with the push notification service.
- When the push notification service receives the notification, it sends it to the device. Notification Hubs has no control on the delivery of the notification to the device at this time.
- Moreover, If the push notification service is unavailable for 30 minutes, the messages will expire and be permanently deleted.
  -If still the issue persists, you can also use Notification hubs REST Api's to obtain notification message telemetry & learn more about a failed delivery message/request against a registration.

Refer [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management.md) for the installation sample template and other relevant information.

Comment: regarding your first point: then the `Start()` method is supposed to update `expireationTime` ahead of 90 days every time when it's called (in my case every time the app starts), but it is not. So registrations are deleted after 90 days.

Comment: regarding 2nd point: What do you mean by "due to an issue with the PNS"?